# How to promote a SQL Server CE database to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I'm new to SQL Server CE, I'd like to ask if I start out small with a file based SQL Server CE database and in the future I want to move up to the regular SQL Server 2008 database, how and what is the best way to convert what I already have up to SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Use my scripting tools /add-ins to script the Compact database, and run the script against a blank SQL Server db

Answer (score 0):

#### Description

At first, it is a good idea to start with `SqlCE` and go to `Sql Server` later.

Looks like you have to write own code to build the tables and populate them with data OR (and this is what i suggest) use a third party tool like primeworks DataPort.

#### More Information

- [Primeworks - Data Port Console](http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortConsole.html)
- [Extracting Data from SQL CE SDF file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/137cd2eb-bb92-4fe7-9994-89f2d1d18a9b/)
- [How can I import data from SQL CE to SQL Server](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/bb37c4e7-d418-467b-8907-d81f9a109020/)
- [Generate Script & Export Data From SQL CE (Compact Edition) 3.5](http://bembengarifin-tech.blogspot.com/2008/08/generate-script-export-data-from-sql-ce.html)